# Unexpected closing of connection, when keep-alive is active

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, keep-alive

I have some trouble with the HTTP connections on our server after a long running transaction. The next request will lead to an exception *java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server*.

It works nicely if I turn off either the keep-alive on the Apache HTTP server or on the JVM from the client.

Setup:

- Apache HTTP server, default config (also tried with increasing the keepalivetimeout to 60secs), connected to tomcat via AJP
- Apache tomcat server, default conf
- Java server application (Spring stack) answering HTTP requests inside tomcat
- Java client (Spring, RestTemplate) -> shooting HTTP calls against this server
- Java client can run on the same server (-> http against localhost) or on another machine, issue stays the same
- iptables disabled on the server
- Just one client was used for the test -> no other client connected to the server at this point in time

What happens?

```
...other stuff...
13:39:32.018 Do Rest call
13:39:32.111 Rest call return headers: Keep-Alive=[timeout=60, max=97], Connection=[Keep-Alive]
13:39:32.609 Do Rest call
13:39:33.849 Rest call return headers: Keep-Alive=[timeout=60, max=96], Connection=[Keep-Alive]
13:39:33.869 Do Rest call
...LONG RUNNING TRANSACTION...
13:40:05.828 Rest call return headers: Keep-Alive=[timeout=60, max=95], Connection=[Keep-Alive]
13:40:05.833 Do Rest call -> _java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server_; no trace in any log file on the server for this request
```

I cannot figure out what causes the connection to be dropped. I cannot find the last failing rest call in any server log. Any idea what it is or what I can do to further isolate the issue?

Here you can see the transactions logged on the server by tshark
[image: Wireshark log]

Comment: No trace of the last call even in apache http server logs?

Comment: Nope nothing there. Access_log / error_log not showing anything for it (loglevel debug)

Comment: It almost looks like you are not connecting to correct remote host/port/protocol at  13:40:05.833, can you add more logging on the client side just to be sure?

Comment: At least that I am sure of -> the calls at 13:40:05.833 is the same as 13:39:32.609 (and I am logging out the whole URL, just deleted it from the log here)

Comment: Then you probably need tcpdump on apache side, to try to see what is really going on

Comment: I just added a image containing the messages logged by tshark on the server side. For me it looks like the server wants to close the connection with package 351, but the client does not care and keeps sending...
Correct?

But why is the server closing the connection? And why is the client not respecting it? Bit lost here, not the expert on TCP level

Answer (score -1):

server side has a connection timeout set so our keep alive connections would timeout after the allocated time and hence the intermittent errors.

remove keep-alive  and try

Comment: The "answer" is already given in the question -> "It works nicely if I turn off either the keep-alive on the Apache HTTP server or on the JVM from the client."